# Python cv2.matchTemplate Результат отличается от ожидаемого

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, opencv, компьютерное-зрение

Раньше код работал идеально, то есть, если картинка совпадала, то `coefficient` был ~0,98.
Теперь функция `cv2.mathTemplate` выдает значения для всех картинок ~0,28
Откатывать код с помощью ctrl+z пробовал, как и переписывать с нуля - не помогает.
Переустанавливал обе библиотеки, менял коэффициенты `threshold`, менял размер области `screen` - тоже не помогает.

Код:

```html
import os
import time
import cv2
import mss
import numpy as np

path = "qwe"

list_l = []
for i in range(len(os.listdir(path))):
    img = np.array(cv2.imread('{}/{}.png'.format(path, i)))

    screen = {"top": 153, "left": 60, "width": img.shape[1], "height": img.shape[0]}
    img_for_compare = np.array(mss.mss().grab(screen))

    img = img.astype('uint8')
    img_for_compare = img_for_compare.astype('uint8')

    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_for_compare = cv2.cvtColor(img_for_compare, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    ret3, img = cv2.threshold(img, 190, 250, 0)
    ret3, img_for_compare = cv2.threshold(img_for_compare, 190, 250, 0)

    time.sleep(0.1)
    cv2.imshow("img", img)
    cv2.imwrite('output/{}.png'.format(i), img)
    cv2.waitKey(25)
    time.sleep(0.1)

    time.sleep(0.1)
    cv2.imshow("img2", img_for_compare)
    cv2.imwrite('output1/{}.png'.format(i), img_for_compare)
    cv2.waitKey(25)
    time.sleep(0.1)

    coefficient = cv2.matchTemplate(img, img_for_compare, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    # coefficient = np.mean(coefficient)

    print("coeff:", np.mean(coefficient), "turn:", i)

    list_l.append((np.mean(coefficient), i))
print(max(list_l))
```

img's:

[0.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARm3l.png)    [1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBr0C.png)    [2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3xgZ.png)    [3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw3uw.png)    [4.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHHAv.png)

imgforcompare:

[0.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqnml.png)

вывод:

```
coeff: 0.27657646 turn: 0
coeff: 0.22043172 turn: 1
coeff: 0.22640704 turn: 2
coeff: 0.30502895 turn: 3
coeff: 0.2658698 turn: 4
(0.30502895, 3)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня правильный результат получился только с параметром `cv2.TM_CCORR`, но там получается не в процентах, в процентах не то выбирает. Но дело тут вовсе не в threshold.

> It only returns good results with identical images, same size & orientation.

У вас на картинках разный несколько размер надписей, из-за этого метрика похожести плывёт. Надо пробовать какой-то другой метод для сравнения найденной картинки с эталоном. `matchTemplate` хорош только для нахождения шаблона в картинке, а для вычисления степени похожести надо использовать уже другие методы, чтобы выяснять, какая из эталонных картинок ближе к найденному по шаблону фрагменту.